# Topojson build fails in Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to follow Mike's tutorial on how to create maps on - http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/.

I have been able to use Node quite well on Windows. I am trying to install topojson with the command - "npm install -g topojson"

I am getting the error -

```
MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available too
ls versions are "4.0".
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sumod_pawgi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\node
_modules\d3\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.16
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am using 64-bit Windows 8.

So looks like there is some mismatch between the .NET version. How can I get the recognized tools version? Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. I had python 2.5 64bit installed as part of the gdal toolkit. Uninstall all the python install's you have. Install python 2.7 x86 as well as nodejs x86. Try using npm to install topojson again.

This worked for me.